# Form Data to mysql using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form with several different information about an user:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name" name="nameD">
<input type="text" id="input-surname" placeholder="Surname" name="surname">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="City" name="city">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Address" name="address">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zipcode">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="State" name="stateR">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="VAT" name="vat">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Fiscal Code" name="fiscalcode">
<input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Bank Account" name="bankaccount">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Bank Name" name="bankname">
<input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Phone" name="phone">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doCreate_User()" value="Create">
```

and by clicking on the create button I call a Javascript function "doCreate_User()".

```
 function doCreate_User(){
  //Actually empty
 }
```

Now, I have a PHP function:

```
 function create_user($name,$surname,...ect){
 //here using INsert into TableX() Values();
}
```

used to insert within a mysql table the variables taken in input from the form.

Which could be a suitable Javascript function able to pass all data from the ***form*** (in HTML, given the event triggered by the onclick) to PHP function ***create_user***?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You pick up the submitted values via the $_POST variables within php ($name = $_POST['nameD'])

Comment: You can take help of : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/7063928

Comment: In HTML, an `id` should be unique in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the following steps to get it working:

1. Create a new page and name it **user.php** (or whatever you want)
2. Paste the following code on the **user.php** page

   ```
    <?php

      function getInputValue($inputName){

       if(isset($_POST[$inputName])){
           return $_POST[$inputName];
       }

       return null;
     }

   $name = getInputValue("nameD");
   $surname  = getInputValue("surname");
   $city  = getInputValue("city");
   .
   .
   .
   $phone = getInputValue("phone");

   function createUser($name,$surname,...){
    //insert your values into the mysql table
   }


   ?>
   ```
3. Inside your create_user function, add the following code

   ```
    function create_user() {
      var userData = $('userForm').serialize();

   var request = {
     "method" : "POST",
     "url" : "user.php",
     "data" : userData,
    };

    $.ajax(request)
     .success(handleSuccess);
    }


    function handleSuccess(response){
       console.log("success");
     }


    </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to stay on the page and not just use a form submit triggered by javascript? I would send an AJAX request with the form as post data to PHP. I prefer using Jquery of Mootools for that, makes it a a tad easier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot command PHP directly from javascript, as javascript is ran on browser and PHP runs on a server. You need to submit your form somewhere, for example a php file, which then parses the input from $_POST (preferrably using filter_input() functions, see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) from php.net).

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jquery
in your javascriptfunction init the ajax request

```
   var jsFormData = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
    url:urlTophpFile,
    method:POST,
    data:jsFormData,
    success:function(response){
    do something after success}

    });
```

now in your php file

```
$data = $_POST; //grabs all the request
```

Grab the value like

```
$data['Name'] $data['surname] etc
//insert to mysql from here
```